# Angular $http service not calling express route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

This is my angular method that would try to send http get request to local server

```
  $scope.getMeth = function(){
            // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9876/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      $scope.serverResponse = response.status;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
      //console.log(response);
      $scope.serverResponse = response.status;
    });
```

And this is the server code using express

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req) {
        console.log(req.url);
        res.send('hello');
    } else {
        console.log('waiting');
    }

});

app.listen(9876, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 9876!');
});
```

I always get error response and -1 status code, what is wrong here?

Comment: why you requesting url like this one `http://127.0.0.1:9876`?

Comment: have you inculde `$http` serrvice in controller

Comment: you can use `http://localhost:9876/` like this

Comment: did you tested it with your browser or some tool to test REST API's??

Comment: @r.j whats wrong with the url? i try to make request to local server

Comment: @wasiqmuhammad yes i already included it

Comment: @paulogaldosandoval i tested it with my browser

Comment: try only using '/' for url

Comment: uhmm thinking you should have problems on cross-origin instead this problem.

Comment: @paulogaldosandoval Thanks so much, i really appreciate it. The problem is indeed on cross-origin, when i inculde cors module, the bug goes away. Thank you so much.

Comment: that's great, glad to help you